# Laravel Nova - Modify/Remove Actions Log UI Section

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I want to remove the default action log UI section below a model's details.

If I remove the "Actionable" trait, then the action log is completely unavailable, including the tabbed pane.

So, I tried making a new class extending the ActionResource class to handle the UI, but I cannot find an interface that controls the UI section. What class/traits/interfaces control the Action log, and how can I hide it from view?

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Actions\ActionResource;


class BetterActionResource extends ActionResource
{
    public static $polling = false;

    public static $showPollingToggle = true;

    /**
     * Get the displayable label of the resource.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function label()
    {
        return __('History');
    }

    /**
     * Get the displayable singular label of the resource.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function singularLabel()
    {
        return __('Event');
    }
}
```

How can I hide the action log while using an Actionable model?

Here is a screenshot to better describe the outcome I am going for.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the package you are using? It should already have something to do so...

Comment: @matiaslauriti https://github.com/eminiarts/nova-tabs
But this is not really a package-specific problem. I was only mentioning it to provide context as to why I want to remove the action log but keep the `Actionable` trait.

Comment: I know it is not a package issue, I understood the package added the history, but you are adding it manually, right ?

Comment: Yes, the package is an addition to Laravel Nova providing the "history" tab. I want to know how to work with Nova to hide the section covered by the red "x" in the picture I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

Add this to your resource class:

```
class User extends Resource
{

    /**
     * Determine if the resource should have an Action field.
     *
     * @param \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function shouldAddActionsField($request)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It overwrites the `shouldAddActionsField` method from the `Laravel\Nova\ResolvesFields` which is added via the parent model (`Laravel\Nova\Resource`). This method determines whether the action field is shown by returning a `bool`.

In the background, actions_events will still be stored in the database and you should be able to access those. I'm not sure how you are accessing them, but I think this should not interfere with that.